# Android Q-municate Error failed to resolve: com.efollestad:material-dialog:0.7.8.1

Tags: android, q-municate

i down load code from https://quickblox.com/developers/Q-municate
after that i import to run and i have error like that:

Error:Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.8.1

Open File

Show in Project Structure dialog

Please Help me, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace Your material Dialog dependency with this:

```
compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Comment: i replace the same you, but it still wrong. Could you have other way?? Help me, please, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure at first you added below in **`build.gradle`** section

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Then add

```
compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.9.1'
```

Comment: I did it, but it still error:  Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.9.1
Show in File  Show in Project Structure dialog

Comment: Thanks your answer :)

Comment: Not work , it still error. Could you download quickblox and run it. Maybe you have the same my error. And could you fix it ???